# can a required field validator can have two validation groups?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am working on a  web page.
In that web page there are 4 text boxes and each one has required field validator.
The web page has 3 buttons.
on clicking on 1st button 1st & 2nd required field validations should fire.
and on 2nd button 2nd and 3rd required field validator should fire 
just like this on 3rd button 3rd and 4th should fire.

The problem is , since the one required field validator is invoked with two buttons i cant have a validation group name .
can anybody please suggest a solution . 
it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JS, where you validate specific groups. For each button create separate validation method.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateGroup12() {
        var g1 = Page_ClientValidate("vgroup1");
        var g2 = Page_ClientValidate("vgroup2");

        if (!g1 || !g2) return false;

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

.aspx edit `RequiredFieldValidator` and set groups name into `ValidationGroup`

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="vgroup1,vgroup2" Display="Dynamic">
```

Comment: i can't have the same required field validator in two different groups!!

Comment: When you do group by group, validation messages will be displayed for the last validated group, in this case only "vgroup2" related validation messages would be displayed. Also, comma seperated validation groups approach is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Have two validators, instead of one validator, for Textbox 2 and Textbox 3 with the validation groups properly set to the corresponding button validation group.

Even though this is going to duplicate the validator, this simplifies your logic.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="vgroup1" Display="Dynamic">

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationGroup="vgroup1" Display="Dynamic">

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationGroup="vgroup2" Display="Dynamic">

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="vgroup1" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="vgroup2" />
```

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but in some situations, both error messages are shown. so, not a goos idea!